# In HTML, is there a way to find out if a particular string is variable?

Tags: html

Let's say I'm looking at a webpage that has a title including the year, such as "StackOverflow 2016". Is there a way, by inspecting the page source, to find out is this string is variable (function automatically updates it every year), or if it is a hardcoded string?

Comment: not really, since that value could be variable on the server. e.g. `<?php echo 'Stackoverflow ' . date('Y'); ?>`. But on the client, you'd only ever see the output of that code, so it's effectively "hardcoded" client-side.

Comment: Good and useful question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to undestand that the web page you see is often generated by code that resides on a server, potentially miles away from you. When you ask for a web page you get simply an HTML page, no more.

So, **generally**, all the methods that generates the data you see on the page cannot be seen client side. Try to imagine what could happen if, let's say, StackOverflow would give you the "power" to see the logic the exists behind web pages of the entire app. You could use these information to do a lot of damage or to steal informations or complex algoritms.

I've said **generally** because data on web page could be generated by javascript, a client side language that can be used to modify the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).
In this case you could see if your string is update by a function.

Comment: Thanks to all for answers, this one was most informative

Answer (score 6):

HTML is for navigator and is the result of a php (or python, etc.) script, so no you can't. (But you can if it is powered by javascript)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way, unless the web site has been specifically coded to make that possible.

I know of one website that does enable marking the variables in its output, but even then, this functionality is turned off for most page requests – it doesn't work unless you explicitly turn it on *for that request*.

Certainly, there is no standard way in html to notice this.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a string variable it is inserted when the page gets created, so to tell if it's hard coded or not you would have to have access to the file which constructs the page - usually a template or a PHP file, etc.. So no, you can't tell if it was a variable or a plain text just from inspecting the source on the client's side.

Answer (score 2):

With one word: No, you can't...

Different scenarios:

By looking at the HTML alone... no, there is no way. Unless, in your specific case, you refresh the page at NYE or something like that... which is silly.

In the HTML is processed on the server.. there is still no way you can know if it is a hardcoded string or a variable.

There might be a chance to see that by looking at front-end source code if the HTML is processed in the client-side of the app...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there would be no way to know this as the source you can see will be what is rendered. So there will be no way to know if this was added with php or js etc.

Comment: If it is added by JS, you can see that.

Comment: By simply looking at the html ? You would need to have a peek at the js source would you not?

Comment: Not necessarly: If the web browser output differs from the HTML source, you know, there is something going on with JavaScript. But anyway: I think he meant on the front-end side (HTML + JS) and not on the back-end side (PHP, ...).